# IPC: collecting data from clients every second

Tags: c, pthreads, semaphore

I want to collect data from all clients connected to my server and I want to wait for it max 1 second. How to do that with semaphores?
My current code:

```
int players=2;
while(1){
    //request for choice
    for(int i = 0; i<players; i++)
        sem_post(&sharedMemory->request_choice);
    //wait for data
    for (int i = 0;i<players; i++)
        //ok..I have data but not in 1 second..
        sem_wait(&sharedMemory->got_choice);


    //updating data..
}
```

Comment: [man sem_timedwait](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_timedwait)

Answer (score 1):

[POSIX platforms provide `sem_timedwait()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sem_timedwait.html):

> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
> #include <semaphore.h>
> #include <time.h>
>
> int sem_timedwait(sem_t *restrict sem,
>        const struct timespec *restrict abstime);
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The `sem_timedwait()` function shall lock the semaphore referenced by
>   `sem` as in the `sem_wait()` function. However, if the semaphore
>   cannot be locked without waiting for another process or thread to
>   unlock the semaphore by performing a `sem_post()` function, this wait
>   shall be terminated when the specified timeout expires.
>
> The timeout shall expire when the absolute time specified by abstime
>   passes, as measured by the clock on which timeouts are based (that is,
>   when the value of that clock equals or exceeds `abstime`), or if the
>   absolute time specified by `abstime` has already been passed at the
>   time of the call.
>
> The timeout shall be based on the `CLOCK_REALTIME` clock. The
>   resolution of the timeout shall be the resolution of the clock on
>   which it is based. The `timespec` data type is defined as a structure
>   in the `<time.h>` header.
>
> Under no circumstance shall the function fail with a timeout if the
>   semaphore can be locked immediately. The validity of the `abstime`
>   need not be checked if the semaphore can be locked immediately.
>
> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> The `sem_timedwait()` function shall return zero if the calling
>   process successfully performed the semaphore lock operation on the
>   semaphore designated by `sem`. If the call was unsuccessful, the state
>   of the semaphore shall be unchanged, and the function shall return a
>   value of `-1` and set `errno` to indicate the error.
>
> **ERRORS**
>
> The `sem_timedwait()` function shall fail if:
>
> ...
>
> ```
> [ETIMEDOUT]
>     The semaphore could not be locked before the specified timeout expired.
> ```

The link also provides this example usage:

> ```
> /* Calculate relative interval as current time plus
>    number of seconds given argv[2] */
>
>
> if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts) == -1) {
>     perror("clock_gettime");
>     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
> }
> ts.tv_sec += atoi(argv[2]);
>
>
> printf("main() about to call sem_timedwait()\n");
> while ((s = sem_timedwait(&sem, &ts)) == -1 && errno == EINTR)
>     continue;       /* Restart if interrupted by handler */
> ```

Comment: Ok, but I want to wait 1 second for all clients at the same time, will it work?

Comment: That would depend on how you implemented your synchronization - you can use more than one semaphore.  There are a lot of ways to handle that in addition to shared memory and semaphores - message queues or pipes come to mind immediately.